# Read and insert data to arrays through loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to read CSV data from a textarea and then depending on the conditions-if they pass or not-push them into two different arrays. I am struggling and I understand why my code inserts the data multiple times(because of my for loops, though I dont know how to fix that)but I do not why it inserts them in both success and failed Arrays. Here is what I have tried so far-must be pure javascript-and excuse my naming which is not great atm:

```
var addValue = document.getElementById('example').value;
filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
  num = /0{2,}|1{2,}|2{2,}|3{2,}|4{2,}|5{2,}/,
  cur = new Date(),
  abbr = ["PA", "CT", "NJ", "MA", "IL", "ID", "OR"],
  successArray = [];
failedArray = [];


if (addValue != "") {
  var CSVvalue = addValue.split(',');
  information.push(CSVvalue);
  for (var i = 0; i <= information.length - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= abbr.length - 1; j++) {
      var email = information[i][3],
        birthdate = new Date(information[i][2]),
        zipCode = information[i][5],
        diff = cur - birthdate,
        age = Math.floor(diff / 31536000000),
        state = information[i][4];


      if ((filter.test(email)) && (!num.test(zipCode)) && (age > 21) && ((state != abbr[j]))) {
        var lastSuccessArray = [];
        successArray.push(information);
        lastSuccessArray.push(successArray.slice(0));

      } else {
        var lastFailArray = [];
        failedArray.push(information);
        lastFailArray.push(failedArray.slice(0));
      }
    }
  }
} else {
  alert("You must enter a value");
}
```

Comment: please go through my code and let me know anything u need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just before pushing to success array check

```
if ( failedArray.indexOf( information[i] ) == -1 )
 {
    successArray.push(information[i]);
 }
```

and vice versa for failed array

```
 if ( successArray.indexOf( information[i] ) == -1 )
 {
    failedArray.push(information[i]);
 }
```

your code can obviously be optimized but for your we will need to know more details about your array and logic.

Comment: I dont really get what you are trying to achieve with your condition here,sorry Im quite new in coding. So how I thought about this problem is read CSV data from the textarea, insert them into "information" array so I can compare the data against the requirements(valid email, age, state, non repeating numbers in zip code)and then if it passes those requirements to insert them into the "success "array otherwise into the "failed" array. You think I am approaching it in a wrong way?

Comment: @user2502490 All I am trying to do here is that if this information is added to one array (failed or success) it shouldn't get added to another array, since after reading your question it occurred to me that an information can either go in success array or failed array. Are you saying that even if the value is in success array, it can get added to failed array as well?

Comment: No you got it right, if it satisfies the if condition it should be pushed into the success array otherwise into the failed array,although your solution didnt work as it keeps adding them to both arrays

Comment: @user2502490 just went through your code again, it should be `information[i]` instead of `information`

Comment: Great thanks,it worked! Theres an other problem now for which I will give you an example as i think is easier to understand. If my first data "a" are passed into the success array it gets passed twice,then every other  data is passed twice to that array but once into the failed array(and vice versa for the failed array)

Comment: @user2502490 is it possible for you to create a simple fiddle so that we can isolate problems?

Comment: Actually i figured it out, it should be failedArray.indexOf( information[i] ) == 1.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

```
var addValue = document.getElementById('example').value;
filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
  num = /0{2,}|1{2,}|2{2,}|3{2,}|4{2,}|5{2,}/,
  cur = new Date(),
  abbr = ["PA", "CT", "NJ", "MA", "IL", "ID", "OR"],
  successArray = [];
failedArray = [];
var information = [];//use array information in here 


if (addValue != "") {
  var CSVvalue = addValue.split(',');
  information.push(CSVvalue);
  for (var i = 0; i <= information.length - 1; i++) {
    //no need of forloop 'j' using in here
      var email = information[i][3],
        birthdate = new Date(information[i][2]),
        zipCode = information[i][5],
        diff = cur - birthdate,
        age = Math.floor(diff / 31536000000),
        state = information[i][4];

      if ((filter.test(email)) && (!num.test(zipCode)) && (age > 21) && ((abbr.indexOf(state) == -1))) {
        var lastSuccessArray = [];
        successArray.push(information);
        lastSuccessArray.push(successArray.slice(0));

      } else {
        var lastFailArray = [];
        failedArray.push(information);
        lastFailArray.push(failedArray.slice(0));
      }

  }
} else {
  alert("You must enter a value");
}
```

Dont use forloop `abbr` this will push values the length of abbr. so instead just use `abbr.indexOf(state) == -1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just saw your edit about the abbr loop(your solution worked)now I want to keep adding data without emptying the arrays every time(eg. after 10 attempts I would like to have "n" entries into the success array and 10-n entries into the failed array).

Comment: yeah i removed second forloop. it is not needed anymore

Comment: please give what u get in addValue. based on that i proceed.

Comment: An example could be: 1,John,4/4/1980,john@mail.com,KY,75930